# Inject parameter into automapper custom ValueResolver using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, automapper

I'm using `automapper` library to convert my `Model` into my `ViewModel`. For each `Model`, I create profile which inside i add my maps using `CreateMap`.

I want to use custom `ValueResolver` in which it will get the logged user ID from `IContext`, so i need to pass implementation of `IContext` using Ninject.

Inside my profile class:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, BusinessModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.ManagerId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<GetManagerResolver>());
```

Then my `GetManagerResolver`:

```
public class GetManagerResolver : ValueResolver<BusinessModel, int>
{
    private IContext context;
    public GetManagerResolver(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override int GetManagerResolver(BusinessModel source)
    {
        return context.UserId;
    }
}
```

But i get this exception message `{"Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args\r\nParameter name: type"}`.

Any Ideas on how make automapper use ninject for object creation?

**UPDATE**
My code to add automapper configuration:

```
public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {            
            cfg.AddProfile(new Profile1());         
            cfg.AddProfile(new Profile2());

            // now i want to add this line, but how to get access to kernel in static class?
            // cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => Kernel.Get(t));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ConstructedBy` function to configure how Automapper should create your `GetManagerResolver` after calling `ResolveUsing`:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, BusinessModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ManagerId, 
         opt => opt.ResolveUsing<GetManagerResolver>()
                   .ConstructedBy(() => kernel.Get<GetManagerResolver>());
```

Or you can globally sepecify your Ninject kernel to be used by Automapper when resolving any type with `Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing` method:

```cs
Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing((type) => kernel.Get(type));
```

Comment: Good, now how can i get refrence to `kernel` inside my automapper configuration class? see my question update

Comment: First: This is now a completely different and unrealted question... Second: there are multiple options: pass it in as parameter to `Configure` store your Kernel in a static field where you create it, etc.

Comment: Did anyone managed to get Ninject working with the ConstructServicesUsing_ ?

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing was to create `NinjectModule` for `Automapper` where I put all my automapper configuration and tell automapper to use `Ninject Kernel` to construct objects. Here is my code:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => Kernel.Get(t));

            cfg.AddProfile(new Profile1());
            cfg.AddProfile(new Profile2());
        });
    }
}
```